# Is SuperSU and TWRP ROM-specific, phone-specific, or not specific at all?

Tags: rooting, twrp, supersu

Whenever I follow a root guide, I see a link to SuperSU and TWRP files. Are these SuperSU and TWRP files the same file for all phones, or is there a different SuperSU for each phone? Also, if it exists for each phone, is it ROM-specific? Do I need a separate SuperSU file for CM13 and stock ROM on the same phone?

Answer (score 4):

SuperSU is generic, same for all (most) devices, some specific devices or methods may require a specific version though.

TWRP is very device specific, each build is customized for the intended device. http://twrp.me is the official site for TWRP which has a database searchable by device.

CM13 is pre-rooted, you do not need SuperSU at all.

Comment: Though it's said that replacing the internal supersu by a "native one" is said to bring more stability and better performance :) But that might be either subjective, device-specific or both. Fact is, it's not necessarily needed.

Comment: @Izzy Guess I've never seen instability in the native superuser of CM based roms, as far as performance goes I'm not sure why one would be faster than the other, a couple milliseconds difference shouldn't be visible to the user, but fine grain configurability could be a factor.

Comment: @acejavelin the one built into CM is not "native" as far as I've heard, but rather "Java", while the other one is binary. But I've not busied myself much with that: if the one present works for you, and you have no issues with it, no reason to switch.

Comment: @Izzy TBH, I gave up on rooting altogether, and in most of my devices custom roms as well, although I used to be flashaholic. With the advent of Marshmallow, things get too complicated with root, Xposed, and custom ROMs always have minor bugs, and owning a Moto X Pure (my current DD device) is very much like having a Nexus device in that it's almost pure Android. It's not perfect, but things work seemlessly. Even though I have written several root tutorials for XDA, and continue to evaluate and test root on multiple devices, for daily use I have given up on it.

Comment: @acejavelin especially with the permission castration on MM, I don't want to use a device running Android 6+ without root and XPosed. One of the reasons I'm still on LP. But we're drifting off :)